# Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred. events=0x8

Tags: android

```
01-03 11:28:47.499: ERROR/InputDispatcher(164): channel '4085fe50 com.bce.tip/com.bce.tip.core.MenuActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
01-03 11:28:47.499: ERROR/InputDispatcher(164): channel '4085fe50 com.bce.tip/com.bce.tip.core.MenuActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!`
```

When I click on Imageview action calling but I am calling this onclick to another layer class

Comment: I suggest you post some code so people are more able to help you.

Comment: scene.addChild(layer);
        
        scene.addChild(new PotShotLayer(this)); 
        scene.getBoundingBox();
        scene.getContentSize();                      
        // Lookup R.layout.main   
        layout.addView(mGLSurfaceView);
       // CCDirector.sharedDirector().runWithScene(scene);
        director.runWithScene(scene);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved :
1) Basically this Errors occurs couple of times
if your running number of process at a time in single thread . 
This is like a Deadlock situation.So any Scheduled tasks are there make it Synchronized particular burden objects. 
2) Kill the unused processes at the time of Burden happens on MainThread.

Comment: So, is there is a standard way to kill all the unused processes at the time of Burden happens?

Comment: I don't understand the answer. Could you explain it further?

Comment: Can you please add a reference?

Comment: @JohnyTex 
1.In short we should not run everything on the main thread.
2. Unused processes are there we can kill them in Ondetach() or onDestory().

Answer (score 5):

It was happening with me at some minutes ago and I found the reason!
This was the code that was causing it:

```
    Canvas pattern = new Canvas();
    Bitmap bitmapPattern = Bitmap.createBitmap(pattern.getWidth(),canvas.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);      
    pattern.setBitmap(bitmapPattern);
    pattern.drawLine(0, 0, 1, 1, paintStroke);  
    paintFill.setShader(new BitmapShader(bitmapPattern, TileMode.REPEAT, TileMode.REPEAT));
```

and the reason is: "pattern.getWidth(),canvas.getHeight()", those parameters may be infinite, I didn't define nothing on canvas yet! CHanging it to numbers I get free from that error!