# How to resolve crashes on starting Activity from menu

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, nullpointerexception, forceclose

I've added menu and in item menu I've added Intent to some Activity for example SettingActivity, but my app crashes however when some other activity is started, that doesn't crash.

I've added Setting class in class I'm using SharedPreferences

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_preferences:
        Intent intent0 = new Intent(this, Setting.class);
        this.startActivity(intent0);
        break;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    return true;
}

public class Setting extends Activity {
    int back;
    private String mood;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.setting_page);
        final TextView sampletxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        SharedPreferences of = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("offon", 0);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor on = of.edit();
        int onf = of.getInt("ofon", 0);
        final Button bs = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bon);

        SharedPreferences size = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("size1", 0);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = size.edit();
        final int ssize = size.getInt("size2", 0);

        SharedPreferences color = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("color1", 0);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = color.edit();
        final int scolor = color.getInt("color2", 0);

        SharedPreferences fontq = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("font1a", 0);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor3 = fontq.edit();
        final int sfont = fontq.getInt("font2a", 0);

        SeekBar sf = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);

        sf.setMax(4);
        sf.setProgress(sfont);
        if (sfont == 0 || sfont == 1) {
            sf.setProgress(1);
            sampletxt.setTypeface(type1);
        } else if (sfont == 2) {
            sf.setProgress(2);
            sampletxt.setTypeface(type2);
        } else if (sfont == 3) {
            sf.setProgress(3);
            sampletxt.setTypeface(type3);
        } else if (sfont == 4) {
            sf.setProgress(4);
            sampletxt.setTypeface(type4);
        } else if (sfont == 5) {
            sf.setProgress(5);
            sampletxt.setTypeface(type5);
        }

        red.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                sampletxt.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                editor2.putInt("color2", 1);
                editor2.commit();
            }
        });

        s_size.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {

                sampletxt.setTextSize(arg1);
                editor1.putInt("size2", arg1);
                editor1.commit();

            }
        });
        sf.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Here's the crash.

```
10-12 16:22:09.663: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(740): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.Zaban/com.example.Zaban.Setting}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.Zaban.Setting.onCreate(Setting.java:89)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
        ... 11 more
10-12 16:22:11.772: ERROR/InputDispatcher(96): channel '4063be30 com.example.Zaban/com.example.Zaban.MyActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
10-12 16:22:11.772: ERROR/InputDispatcher(96): channel '4063be30 com.example.Zaban/com.example.Zaban.MyActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
10-12 16:22:12.542: ERROR/InputDispatcher(96): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=149, events=0x8
10-12 16:22:12.552: ERROR/InputDispatcher(96): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=155, events=0x8
```

Comment: have you put your setting activity to manifest?

Comment: yes im put activity to manifist

Comment: im realy know why force close

Comment: change your intents with this

Intent intent = new Intent(yourcurrentactivity.this,Setting.class);
startActivity(intent);

Comment: change it but force close

Comment: Can you post contents of the Settings class?

Comment: can you post the logcat

Comment: Are you see my logcat and setting code

Comment: im added part of setting Activity this activity work well

Comment: Just to make sure, are your activities in different files?

Comment: And copy your complete error in your question...

Comment: yes i puted in diffrent file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869289/consumer-closed-input-channel-or-an-error-occurred-events-0x8

Comment: You're setting `OnClickListener` to a variable `red`. I don't see you've initialized it. Make sure you've initialized it. Also your `s_size` seems to be `null` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function for startnewactivity and call the function in menu.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        case R.id.home:
            openNewIntent(YourClass.class);
            return true;
}}


private void openNewIntent(Class a)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(this, a);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: please write more explanation

Comment: In my opinion your Setting class is wrong. Check it.

Comment: no when intent from another class to setting class it work well

Comment: please say me another way fr intent from menu